# Fix Element not Interactable Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to create a raffle autocheckout on feature.com using C# and Selenium. I got through everything up to the payment page, where the payment fields (card,expiry, etc) are "not interactable". I've tried everything from using tag names, xpath, and nothing. This is my code:

```
            const string cardName = "John A Doe";
            const string expiry = "1224";
            const string cvv = "001";

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/input")).SendKeys(card);
           driver.FindElement(By.Id("card-holder")).SendKeys(cardName);
           driver.FindElement(By.Id("card-expiry-date")).SendKeys(expiry);
           driver.FindElement(By.Id("card-cvc")).SendKeys(cvv);
```

Comment: Did this get resolved?

Comment: Still working on it. Appreciate the advice, though.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that since this is a payment, it is probably in an iframe. You will need to switch to it and then add the cc info and the switch to main window to continue.

That first xpath needs to be fixed. That is a recipe for failure. If you post the html we can help you with a better path.

I just realized you posted the site. It is in an iframe and you can't get to the card name because it is in an iframe.

Based on this I would used the below but these fields are hidden which is always fun to deal with.

```
   SwitchToIframeByXpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'card-fields-number')]");
   driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//input[@placeholder='Card number']")).SendKeys(cardNum);
   SwitchToMainContent;
   SwitchToIframeByXpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'card-fields-name')]");
   driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//input[@placeholder='Name on card']")).SendKeys(cardName)
   SwitchToMainContent;
```

Rinse repeat for each field.

```
    public static void SwitchToIframe(string frameName)
    {
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName);
    }
```

or by xpath

```
      public static void SwitchToIframeByXpath(string title)
    {
      driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(title)));

    }
```

Then switch to main

```
    public static void SwitchToMainContent()
    {
             driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    }
```

Comment: If the elements were in an IFRAME, it wouldn't throw ElementNotInteractable, it would throw ElementNotFound. ElementNotInteractable means you can't interact with that element, e.g. maybe it's not visible.

Comment: Jeff - It is in an iframe. He posted the site feature.com. He is failing on the card number because that first element he is looking for is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I'm not saying that *some* aren't in an IFRAME but my first comment stands. He stated that he was getting "not interactable" messages. This will not happen to elements in an IFRAME. Maybe he's posted the wrong error message for this code.